Unable to Retrieve Online Meetings Data Using Microsoft Graph API
I'm currently working on an application that needs to retrieve all online meetings for a specific user using the Microsoft Graph API. Despite following the official documentation, I'm encountering an issue where the request returns no data.
Here's the endpoint I'm using:
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{userId}/onlineMeetings

{
    "error": {
        "code": "UnknownError",
        "message": "",
        "innerError": {
            "date": "2024-06-17T06:15:45",
            "request-id": "eef00a47-1aa0-418a-894f-6a79037000be",
            "client-request-id": "eef00a47-1aa0-418a-894f-6a79037000be"
        }
    }
}


Could you include more details like how you generated the token and what API permissions you granted?

Authentication token is generated using Client ID and secret. I have granted permissions for Users and Calendar. Do I need additional permission to access online meetings?

Are you using client credentials flow to generate token? If yes, you must create application access policy and grant it to a user to authorize the app configured in the policy. Refer this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/onlinemeeting-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#permissions.

Initially I registered one application and granted OnlineMeetings.ReadWrite.All permission of Application type that allows access to create meetings as well:

Make sure to create application access policy and grant access as below while using permissions of Application type by logging with Admin account:
Install-Module -Name MicrosoftTeams -Force -AllowClobber

Import-Module MicrosoftTeams
Connect-MicrosoftTeams

New-CsApplicationAccessPolicy -Identity Demo-policy -AppIds "appId" -Description "Allow access to Teams App"

Grant-CsApplicationAccessPolicy -PolicyName Demo-policy -Global

Response:

Now I generated access token using client credentials flow via Postman like this:
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenantId/oauth2/v2.0/token

grant_type:client_credentials
client_id: appId
client_secret: secret
scope: https://graph.microsoft.com/.default

Response:

When I used this token to create online meetings with below API call, I got response like this:
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/userId/onlineMeetings
{
  "startDateTime":"2024-06-18T14:30:34.2444915-07:00",
  "endDateTime":"2024-06-18T15:00:34.2464912-07:00",
  "subject":"Group Meeting"
}

Response:

To retrieve this online meeting data, you must either use meeting ID or filter with joinWebUrl for which the user is the organizer or attendee.
Using Meeting ID:
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/userID/onlineMeetings/meetingID/

Response:

Filtering with joinWebUrl:
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/userID/onlineMeetings?$filter=joinWebUrl eq 'https://teams.microsoft.com/l/meetup-join/xxxxxxxxxxxx'

Response:

You cannot get all online meetings for a user at once as Graph API does not yet support List onlineMeetings method.
References:
Issue with MS Graph API to retrieve online meeting information - Microsoft Q&A by Carl Zhao - MSFT
Get onlineMeeting - Microsoft Graph

Hi @Sridevi I have found a more feasible solution to my issue . Instead using online meetings or listing events (which wasn't all the records btw) , I have tried calendarview api which works absolutely what I need .

Yes @Rik That also works!
